# Localhost, wordpress site links to files with wrong paths compared to real site (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: html, wordpress, ubuntu, web, localhost

I tried to make localhost of a WordPress site but it doesn't work. It displays only `navbar` without any styles and any different content.

It is the site that is published and is working correctly. The files are copied from `repo on GitHub` so, I guess the problem is not connected with these files. I have this **repo in directory** `/var/www/html`.

After many hours i found out that **my directories to css, js and other file are different than the directories on a proper site**.

For example:

- On my localhost page it looks like this: **href="/assets/img/favicon.ico?ver=3"**
- On site: **href="/wp-content/themes/page/assets/img/favicon.ico?bfcb62"**

Many other files are missing this part of path: `/wp-content/themes/page/` .
How can I change it?

I will also add that

> php echo get_template_directory_uri();

doesn't show anything.

I have a database file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `wp-config.php` from a different person. On his computer, it works so I guess there is not a problem but I don't know.

Also in this project node, gulp, bower are used.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: For migrating a wordpress website if you are not that familiar with manual steps, please use the plugin 'duplicator' so you can directly install a copy just by giving the new location details.

Comment: Is it a WordPress plugin? And could you maybe try to find a solution for my problem?